# ForeignKey to multiple Models or Queryset

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-queryset

Is it possible to make a ForeignKey to more than one model? I want to choose from different models like Parts and Machines Model.

I read this to combine multiple models into one list: [How to combine multiple querysets in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view)

How can I get the foreign key to that list?

Answer (score 27):

I know that you asked this over a year ago, but I had a similar problem and I want to share a link to the solution for future readers.

Generally [the contenttypes framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) solves this problem, and I guess this is what Daniel Roseman was talking about.

[How to use dynamic foreignkey in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881792/how-to-use-dynamic-foreignkey-in-django)

Comment: Unfortunately, with this method and how it implements `GenericForeignKey`, you can't use the database API so it was a non-starter for my particular use case.

Comment: How can you not use the API with that?

Answer (score 10):

You need [generic relations](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations).

A generic relation allows you to dynamically the target model of the foreign key.

Comment: would you mind explaining how this will work with my example?

Comment: I might have been unclear. I want to be able to choose from multiple objects from different models. So its a combination of parts and machines. So in the dropdown list i would have ex: Drilling machine, Press, 1.5mm angle iron, 1v switch etc etc

Comment: This link is dead

Answer (score 2):

*I'll provide a comprehensive answer for this question, I know its quite old, but it's still relevant.*

We're gonna be using [Generic Relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations).

First, in `settings.py` make sure that `django.contrib.contenttypes` is included in the `INSTALLED_APPS` array.

Let's create a new model in `models.py`:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey, GenericRelation
```

With `content_type` we can associate `Image` with any other model class, while `object_id` will hold the other model instance.

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(
      upload_to="imgs/products", blank=True)

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()
```

To refer back to the `Image` model from a `Company` instance we need to make a [reverse generic relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations)

```
class Company(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  images = GenericRelation(Image)
```

In `schema.py`, we can create `Image`s in a `Company` instance like:

```
company_instance = Company(name="Apple")
company_instance.save()
for img in imgs:
    #Image(image=img, content_object=company_instance)
    company_instance.images.create(image=img)
company_instance.images.all() # fetch all images
```

the `company_instance.images` field is just a `GenericRelatedObjectManager` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/))

This is how the final `Image` table looks in the database:
[image: image table]

Answer (score 0):

The [Django-polymorphic library](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) provides a simple solution that should work well with the admin and forms too using formsets.

For example:

```
from polymorphic.models import PolymorphicModel


class BookOwner(PolymorphicModel):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class StaffBookOwner(BookOwner):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Staff, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class StudentBookOwner(BookOwner):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

With this, you can use the parent model to set the owner to either a `Staff` or `Student` instance or use the child models directly.