# Understanding relationships in django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to django. I'm struggling with relationships.
I have 4 apps (app1, app2, app3, app4). App2, 3 and 4 have the same fields. And those fields have to be in app1. How can i write my models? Please help.
For example app1 is movies(with title and location), app2 is music(with title and location) and app3 is ballet(with title and location). App1 has to be cinema where we have movies, music performances and ballets.

Comment: You need to first take a look at basic database concepts and design principles. Normalization, Foreign Keys, Many to one, many to many all these will come into play with your app, based on what little information you have provided. Once you have this information, you can try defining your models and post some code that you have tried and does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure your business model, I presume:

```
class Cinema:
    movies = models.ManyToManyField('app1.Movie')
    music = models.ManyToManyField('app2.Music')
    etc...
```

Alternatively, if you want movies to assign to one cinema only:

```
class Movie:
    cinema = models.ForeignKey('app1.Cinema', related_name='movies')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried this approach, it seems not working